# Conditional display of form fields Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation, conditional-statements, ionic5

I am currently developing an app using Ionic Angular. I want to have the user select an option, and based off of that option, I want he/she to see a specific form field. For example, in Google Forms, or Microsoft Forms, I can select something, and a question related to what I selected pops up, how do I do this? I have done Form Validation, but I want to see how I can do the conditional display of form fields.

Comment: look at `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy! Angular Reactive forms is a highly advanced way of using forms and form validations in angular..You can do something like this:

```
// In your component.ts file, you can define a formGroup and formControls like this

someFormGroup = new FormGroup({

  formControl1: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  formControl2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  formControl3: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
})


// In your HTML file, you can define like this.

<div [formGroup]="someFormGroup">
   <input type="radio" name="formContol1" formControlName="formControl1" placeholder="Select any option"/>

// to check the value and display formfields, you need to do this

   <div *ngIf="someFormGroup.get('formControl1).value === true">
      /// Some HTML content
   </div>

   <div *ngIf="someFormGroup.get('formControl1).value !== true">
      /// Some other HTML content
   </div>
</div>
```